# Can you tell the DirectionsRenderer which route to take if you specified provideRouteAlternatives as true in your call to DirectionsService

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

if you have a response from DirectionsService that has multiple routes in the response object, because you set provideRouteAlternatives to true, DirectionsRenderer just displays the first one in the routes array.

I want to be able to specify which route the DirectionsRenderer will display.

I am sure I can rebuild a response object that has a single element arrray with just has the route I want but I was hoping something already existed given it is possible to have multiple routes in your response.

thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the [`routeIndex` in the `DirectionsRendererOptions`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRendererOptions) Object (from the documentation):

> **routeIndex**
>
> Type:  number
>
> The index of the route within the DirectionsResult object. The default value is 0.)

(or call the [`setRouteIndex` function on the `DirectionRenderer`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRenderer) sometime after you have created it):

> **setRouteIndex(routeIndex:number)**
>
> Return Value:  None
>
> Set the (zero-based) index of the route in the DirectionsResult object to render. By default, the first route in the array will be rendered.

**Related question:** [Display multiple routes between two points on Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35050401/display-multiple-routes-between-two-points-on-google-maps)

**Note:** You need to make your call to setRouteIndex() on the DirectionsRenderer **after** you call setDirections(response).  the documentation doesn't state that for the setRouteIndex() call but alludes to it when it mentions the setOptions() have to be called after Initialization.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I don't know how I missed that in the documentation. Dumb user error.